# how to reset component properties in Vue js?

Tags: vuejs2

I am trying to make a product review page using Vue js. Please see the below code

**App.Vue**

```
<template>
<div class=" wrapper">
<div class="container shadow padding-left-none">
  <div class="grid-100 padding-left-none">
    <div class="grid-30 padding-left-none">
      <product-list></product-list>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-70">
      <reviewPage :reviews="reviews"></reviewPage>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</template>
```

**review-page.vue**

```
    <template>
    <div class="grid-100">
        <div class="review-wrapper">
            <h3>Rate this product</h3>
            <div class="rating-section">
                <div class="user-ratings">
                    <rating-star v-on:ratingProvided="ratingProvided"></rating-star>
                </div>
                <div class="rating-complement" v-if="isRatingProvied">
                    <span class="complement">{{ratingComplement}}</span>
                </div>
                <div class="rating-saved pull-right" v-if="isRatingSaved">
                    <span class="saved-status">Your rating has been saved</span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="reviews-container">
                <div class="review" v-for="review in reviews" :key="review.id">

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

product-list is having product.vue components.

whenever i am selecting a produc, the properties of review-page components are not getting reset. I want to reset "isRatingProvied" property.so that a fresh review page will be rendered for every product selection.

Comment: I think you also need to include your <script> part if you want an answer

Comment: You should send the `isRatingProvided` to your `reviewPage` component like this `<reviewPage :reviews="reviews" :isRatingProvided="rating > 0"></reviewPage>` and reset the `rating` each time a new product is selected.